# Why is Used + Available disk space always less than Total disk space?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

```
root@localhost:~ $ df /dev/sdb1
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1            1922858352  23247088 1801935664   2% /mnt/external/sdb1
```

used+available = 1825182752

Size - 1825182752  = 97675600

Comment: You've obviously meant `Size - 1825182752`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`97675600 / 1825182752 = 5%` this is the default reserved space for root user.

Comment: That's an interesting point, however I would expect df to tabulate the physical usage, and not to take into account such a reservation.  Is there a switch or a different utility that shows the physical available space?

Comment: Does it run into issues when the 5% threshold is breached? any way to change this value?